# Return current path with a GND pin at signal source

Tags: displacement-current, return-current

I regularly see images of 2D solvers that showcase how return currents flow under the signal track/path as the frequency of the signal rises. A result of such a solver:

[image: return path as frequency rises]
[source of image](https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/articles/1771-a-simple-demonstration-of-where-return-current-flows)

But I noticed, they always use one pin/point (I guess Signal only) at the source and not two (Signal and Return). I have not used a 2D solver so I am not sure of the exact configurations of the simulation, but how does the high frequency current flow in a more-realistic scenario (where the signal/return paths are close together), as the Red or Green path?:

[image: return path with two input pins]

Comment: Those simulations have both a signal and ground connected at the source, otherwise there would be no circuit.

Comment: What that graphic doesn't show is that in that kind of demo, there are 2 return paths from the load to the source.  One is a direct path, vertically along the left of the graphic.  The other is a path that follows the signal source  path but in the reverse direction, CCW in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Neither red nor green really, without knowing the sourcing component. The return current will go all the way to the very pin that sourced the forward current. I.e. to the GND connection of the IC, through the IC and to the output pin. Only this way does it become a loop.

During this loop, high frequency currents will attempts to stay as close as possible to the forward current at all points. This happens because further out paths have increased impedance (inductance).

If the sourcing IC is on the top of your render, then green is more likely. If its on the bottom side, red is more likely.

Answer (score 0):

At low frequencies, the current follows the least resistance. At high frequencies, the current follows the least inductance i.e. the smallest loop which is right underneath the signal trace because the ground plane on the bottom layer and the signal trace on the top layer form distributed capacitances. From \$C=\varepsilon A/d\$, as the distance between these two decreases the capacitance increases, so it gets easier for the high-frequency signal to flow "through the PCB" and return underneath the trace:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHoRxV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As for your case shown in the image in your question, it's difficult to answer without knowing the properties. But the section can be modelled as four parts:

- The trace segment from the VCC pin to the resistor *(assuming the signal is coming directly on top. If it's coming from the bottom then the via should also be included.)*
- Resistor *(including terminal inductances)*
- The trace segment after the resistor to the via
- Via

The first and the third sections are both pretty much the thing I have shown above. The second section, along with the PCB capacitances, may exhibit a low-pass filter behaviour. The fourth section will exhibit an inductance and a resistance.

Some of the high-frequency components (i.e. the components that represent the fast rising/falling of the signal – high dv/dt) will probably return underneath the first section because there's a resistor and a via (inductance and resistance) along the path. The "remaining" relatively low-frequency components after the resistor, depending on the circuit parameters, may flow "through" the PCB, reach the GND plane, and finally follow the least inductance. If some of the frequency components are high enough then these components may not flow through the via actually due to the via's inductance. And finally, the remaining low-frequency components will flow through the via and find the least resistance path to the GND.

So, in short, difficult to answer as "red" or "green".